# Reading a matrix containing negative numbers and store in array. C

Tags: c, file

I need to read a file contains a matrix. The question is what if the matrix includes negative numbers also?

```
2  -20   1
5   -4  -312
10   4    -3
```

Suppose that the file contains this. How can I read it and store in an `int` array? Language is C. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 2 -20 1 is first row

Comment: 5 -4 -312 is the second row

Comment: 10 4 -3 is third row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative numbers are treated the same as positive numbers. The [documentation for `fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf) explicitly says so:

> `d`   Decimal integer Any number of decimal digits (0-9), *optionally preceded by a sign* (+ or -).
>   (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf)

So if you use `%d` in `fscanf`, you don't need to do anything special for negative numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[3][3];
    int row,col;
    FILE *read_file;

    read_file = fopen ("matrix.txt", "r");
    for (row=0; row<3; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col<3; col++)
        {
            if (fscanf (read_file, "%d", &matrix[row][col]) < 1)
            {
                printf ("unexpected end of file or other error\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose (read_file);

    for (row=0; row<3; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col<3; col++)
        {
            printf ("%4d ", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

   return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
   2  -20    1 
   5   -4 -312 
  10    4   -3
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. But the code you wrote above isnt working. When I try it , all the matrix array elements are 0 .

Comment: Sorry I found the problem and thanks for your help. You are right :)

Comment: @AybarTaş: it works -- as you can see in the "result" part. But I had to invent my own input file because you did not provide one in your question.

Comment: And if the matrix I am gonna use was dynamic two dimentional ? will anything changes ?